# Missing create methods for generated classes in ObjectFactory

Tags: jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin

We use jaxb2-plugin to generate some classes and we depend on Object factory while creating JaxbContext.

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Messaging</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <packageName>com.abc.message</packageName>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <schemaInclude>abc/api/message/main.xsd</schemaInclude>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                        <bindingIncludes>
                            <bindingInclude>abc/api/message/binding.xjb</bindingInclude>
                        </bindingIncludes>
                        <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                        <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd</bindingDirectory>
                        <generateDirectory>jaxb2-generated-sources/messaging</generateDirectory>
                        <removeOldOutput>true</removeOldOutput>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <verbose>false</verbose>
                        <args>
                            <arg>-target</arg>
                            <arg>2.2</arg>
                            <arg>-Xequals</arg>
                            <!--arg>-XhashCode</arg-->
                            <arg>-Xlocator</arg>
                            <arg>-Xinheritance</arg>
                            <arg>-Xcopyable</arg>
                        </args>
                        <plugins>
                            <plugin>
                                 <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                                 <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                                 <version>0.6.0</version>
                            </plugin>
                        </plugins>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

In main.xsd I have include schema - something like below:

```
<xsd:schema .... >
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="includeMe.xsd"/>
    <xsd:element name="Job">
        .....
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

and contents of includeMe.xsd:

```
 <xsd:schema .... >
    <xsd:element name="JobDef">
        .....
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Problem:
Even though JAXB is generating all the classes (Job and JobDef) properly still ObjectFactory only contains create methods defined in main.xsd.

Question: How do I generate ObjectFactory properly so that create methods for all the generated classes are in there?

Any pointers ?

Karephul